# Set wpf datagrid cell value programmatically

Tags: wpf, datagrid

I have a simple datagrid with 2 columns, ProductCode and Description.
When user compile a ProductCode in the first column and move to the next column, the program should compile the Description cell with the description of the product found in the Products table.
What is the best approach to do this?

Comment: Handle data changes inside the object which each row in your DataGrid represents.

Comment: Ok, but what is the correct event to handle data changes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What is the best approach to do this?

Define a class with two properties, `ProductCode` and `Description`, that implements the [INotifyPropertyChanged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged(v=vs.110).aspx) interface. You can then lookup the description of the products in the setter of the `ProductCode` property, e.g.:

```
public class Product : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _productCode;
    public string ProductCode
    {
        get { return _productCode; }
        set
        {
            _productCode = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged();
            LookupProduct();
        }
    }

    private string _description;
    public string Description
    {
        get { return _description; }
        set { _description = value; NotifyPropertyChanged(); }
    }

    private void LookupProduct()
    {
        //loop up product based on _productCode here
        //...and set the Description property:
        Description = "...";
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

You should of course also set or bind the `ItemsSource` property of the `DataGrid` to an `IEnumerable<Product>`.

Comment: This is excactly what i did, but the PropertyChanged event fire only when user changes row and the row is added to the datasource. I would like to let user see the product description after compiling the product code, even if the row isn't added yet, when cursor exit from the productcode cell and goes to the description cell in the same row

Comment: @MassimoSpinelli In your XAML code do you set the UpdateSourceTrigger for each of the datagrid columns to "OnPropertyChanged"?

Comment: @PaulGibson This is the final piece of the puzzle! Thank you!