# How to edit cells in wpf?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

Hi please tell me how to edit **Cells** in DataGrid WPF C#, in winfoms it is **mydata.Rows[0].Cells[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ynpxz.png).Value = "xxxx";**, how about in WPF how to fix ?

[image]

[image]

Comment: You set the corresponding property of the data object in the `ItemsSource`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change DataGrid cell value programmatically in WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12164079/change-datagrid-cell-value-programmatically-in-wpf)

Comment: @mm8, you have already [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44050928/1997232) similar question (with a small twist).

Comment: @Sinatr I have added 2 image links to the question, my xaml code is in Figure 1 and can you give me some example c# code to edit the content of Cell Message (img 2), I tried the way you gave can't get out